# C: Using hexadecimal to represent UTF-8 (like Euro)

Tags: c, utf-8, binary, hex, symbols

I'm new to the world of C, so bear with me. And I've searched high and low for an answer to this, but have yet to understand it clearly.

I am trying to input and output, for example, the Euro symbol **€** (an extended character value). I want to use hexadecimal byte combinations. For the Euro, they are:    0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC    . I understand that in C++, you can simply use \u20ac, which is not the case in C.

I have tried assigning the hex values to an int, but that did not work for me. I have also tried using the Euro symbol's decimal value.

The idea behind my program is to take user input (e.g. €100) and convert it to a different currency. So differentiating the currency symbols is my main issue at hand. Is there another way to go about this than what I have tried?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal, `u8"€"`.

Comment: You can also use `\u20ac` in C. Who said you can't?

Comment: I tried using it and it threw an error (C99 error or something). Did some research and someone somewhere said it is for C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `€` can be represented with 3 `char`'s.

So you can do it like this.

```
char str[] = { 0xE2, 0x82, 0xAC, 0x00 };
printf("str: \"%s\"\n", str);
```

The output:

> str: "€"

Comment: Well that was less complicated than I thought. Thanks a bunch